# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de hacer un request en un Api rest con node.js y express?

Tags: nodejs, api

intente hacerlo de esta forma, que reciba el datos por req que lo pase a la funcion decodificar y con res retorne los datos decodificado. El tema es que no funciona y quería ver si lo hice de forma correcta.

```
//Decodificar
const InputDataDecoder = require('ethereum-input-data-decoder');
const decoder = new InputDataDecoder(`${__dirname}/ABI.json`);  

function decodificar(data){
   var result = decoder.decodeData(data);    
   return result;
}

//Express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/decode/:DatoEntrada', function(req, res){    
    var inputdata = req.param.DatoEntrada;
    var decode = decodificar(inputdata);
    res.send(decode);
});    
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: te falta agregar los parámetros de `request` y `response` a tu funcion del método _get_; estas llamando a **req.param.DatoEntrada** pero no existe ningún request

Comment: Gracias, no me había dado cuenta de ese pequeño error xd

Comment: Funcionó? Te lanza algún error?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera ya arregle el pequeño error pero no recibo el dato codificado a traves del req.para.DatoEntrada

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera no puedo mostrar el dato que envio a la funcion get. Estoy postman para probarlo y lo hago asi "localhost:8080/decode/dato-codificado" o no?

Comment: Eso depende la forma en que configuraste tu entorno... generalmente se realiza como **localhost:puerto/api/metodo/parametro** ..

Comment: o sea en el parte del api tendria que ir el app.get o get?

Comment: Como te comente, eso es parte de la configuración de cada desarrollador, por lo que si no configuraste que tuviera el prefijo **api**, no debes colocarlo...

Comment: Ya supe el error que tenia, el tema es que estaba haciendo req.param.DatoEntrada pero me falto la 's' del params por eso no podía recibir el dato. Le agradezco por la ayuda que me ha dado porque soy nuevo en el tema del Api rest asi que muchas gracias.

Comment: @NicolasFloresMuñoz. Tienes un error al solicitar `param` en tu objeto `req`. La forma correcta es `req.params` en plural. Puedes consultar la [API Express](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html). Verifica eso. Además debes verificar si recibes el parámetro antes de intentar trabajar con él.

Comment: @MauricioContreras me di cuenta del error y lo solucione, ademas de verificar que este funcionando correctamente, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: @NicolasFloresMuñoz Si mi respuesta fue útil para usted, puede aceptarla o calificarla para que otros usuarios con un problema similar puedan encontrar una solución más rápido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a tu problema es la siguiente: `var inputdata = req.params.DatoEntrada;`

> **req.param** no existe!

**req.params** 
Esta propiedad es un objeto que contiene propiedades asignadas a los "parámetros" de la ruta indicada.

**req.query** 
Contiene los parámetros de consulta de la URL (después de? en la URL)

**req.body** 
Contiene pares clave-valor de datos enviados en el cuerpo de la solicitud.

Espero que esto te ayude a entender cuando usar cada expresión y a solventar tu duda.

Comment: `req.params` tendrá información siempre y cuando se especifiquen como parte estructural de la URL y `req.body` tendrá informacón siempe y cuando sea una petición POST y se incluya contendo en el cuerpo de la misma.